# Regex to search behind from A to B

Tags: regex

Given a string such as:

```
/level0/level1/level2/abc.exe vndjvnrjv
```

I would like to extract `"abc.exe"`

I have no clue when it comes to regex; I wonder how to do that?

Comment: There are lots of possible ways to answer this question — the difficulty is knowing what else you want to match.  Given `/level0/abc.exe/level1/level2 wondering`, what would you want extracted?  Given `/level0/level1/level2/porcupine sticky` what would you want extracted?  Given `/level0/level1/abc.exe minimalist`, what would you want extracted?  Also, which sub-species of regex are you using — what's the host language?  Without such information, people can come up with all sorts of inventive answers that may be no help to you at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use look arounds either end:

```
(?<=\w/)[\w.]+(?=\s)
```

The look arounds assert that:

- the input immediately before the target is "word-char slash"
- the input immediately after the target is "whitespace"

The entire match is your target.